# UIWebView hidden by keyboard

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, keyboard, textfield

I have iPad app with view and `uiwebview` in it. It is on the bottom with size smaller than keyboard (e.g. 300x200). In webview is page with form loaded. 
When I tap into some textfield, keyboard pops up and hides whole uiwebview. With iOS simulator and slow animation mode I can see, that webview is scrolled, but when it is smaller then keyboard and at the bottom, it is useless. Webview is covered with keyboard.

I have mastered moving hidden content by keyboard according [managing keyboard documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) but when i set `scrollview` offset, `webview` still do the scrolling and scrolls text input away. There isn't way of setting `webview` offset.
Also I found in `UIWebView` class reference important note that embed `webview` in `scrollview` won't work correctly.

It seems to me i have come across easy problem but with no solution on the Internet. So am I first who wants to have `uiwebview` smaller than fullscreen? Is it app Store correct to have small `uiwebview`? What to do if `UIWebView` is hidden by keyboard?

Thanks for any notes and suggestions.

Comment: I have tried changing frame of view so it will move up when keyboard pops up. I don't like this solution because then you have to close keyboard to see or tap things on top. I'm looking for scrolling content so the user could scroll around and see or tap things in upper part of screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the keyboard when the webView is scrolled, try this:

```
self.webView.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode =UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is Keyboard notifications. You can scroll the view upwards using the methods provided by the UIView class nad this link should help you out greatly.

[Keyboard Hiding Screen](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/keyboard.html)

Comment: Thank you for idea. I have tried this. Sorry, I forgot to mention it in question message. I wasn't satisfied with result. This way you just shift the screen up and you can't tap anything that goes off screen.

Comment: why don't you have the initial size of the webview set to full screen, and in the method that shows you're using the keyboard, set the size of the webview, that way you can scroll it up to tap on the things off screen

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I set the webview to full screen or to the height of fullscreen, other webview under it will be hidden be it.